# Кентаврица или кентавриха?

Tags: суффиксы

Поиск склоняет к "Х", но с "Ц" звучит приятнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понятно, что "кентавриды" - правильная форма.
Но если говорить о предложенных формах "кентаврица" и "кентавриха", то у них скорее всего будут разные значения.

Феминизирующие суффиксы "-иха" и "-ица" редко встречаются у одной основы, но какую-то закономерность можно проследить на примерах из рядов с этим морфом.

Во-первых, видно, что "-ица" редко применимо к "мужским" образованиям с суффиксом "-ец", единственное, чего вспомнил: *чернец-черница, молодец-молодица и палец-палица*(с неочевидной парностью), в других случаях или "-иха": *купец-купчиха, гребец-гребчиха*, или вообще нормативная форма отсутствует: *борец-(?)борчиха, гонец-(?)гончиха*.

Так что по этой модели "кентавриха" можно скорее связать с "кентаврец", чем с "кентавр".

А вот для остальных случаев наблюдается следующее.

*Мастер-мастерица, волк-волчица* (с устарелым *волчиха*) - примеров немного,  но они характерны тем, что женский род - это именно парный к мужскому, *мастерица* - это именно мастер женского полу. Сюда же условно парные образования на "-ель"-"-ельница": *учитель-учительница, житель-жительница*.

И напротив:

*Мельник-мельничиха, сторож-сторожиха* - тут примеров вагон.  Как привило, они означают **жену**, а не профессию или носителя свойства.

Есть и обратные примеры, но тут сложно провести скрупулезный статистический анализ,  доверяюсь своим ощущениям.

Таким образом, по моим ощущениям, **кентаврица** - это женская особь кентавра, то есть *кентаврида*, а **кентавриха** - жена кентавра, которая может и не быть *кентавридой* - ну мало ли, до каких там смешанных браков древние могли додуматься.

Вот как-то так...

Answer (score 4):

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80):

> Кентавры женского пола, или **кентавриды** (лат. Centaurides, в просторечии **кентаврицы**) редко встречались в живописи и мифах, играя в основном роль эпизодических персонажей, и зачастую их путали с нимфами. При этом, немногие авторы, упоминающие о их существовании, описывали их как созданий прекрасных физически и духовно[15]. Наиболее известной **кентавридой** является Гилонома, жена Киллара (Циллара). Она — единственная женщина из рода кентавров, которая побывала на свадьбе Пирифоя, где она потеряла мужа, а затем покончила с собой от горя[16].

Из Нацкорпуса:

> (Отсутствие абажура населяло помещение фантастическими гротескными тенями, и выглядело оно местом, куда слетелись сказочные птицы и сбежались вместе с реальными жителями Харькова кентавры и **кентаврессы**…) [Эдуард Лимонов. У нас была Великая Эпоха (1987)]